# Should I be changing temperature min and max or reaction speed if I want my flames to go higher?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

Working on a fire simulation and I was confused about which value is more physically correct to adjust because I know adjusting reaction speed slows down or speeds up the fire simulation.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A high *Fuel* value will bring more fuel and make higher (but also bigger and more agitated) flames. A low *Reaction Speed* will speed up the reaction and make higher flames as well. To make higher flames you can also try these factors:

Select the inflow object, enable *Initial Velocity* and choose a high value on Z:

[image]

Or select the domain and under *Gas*, increase the *Buoyancy Heat*:

[image]